# How to correctly deal with one-hot-encoding and multi-dimensional data in tensorflow RNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I'm creating a binary classifier that classifiers letter sequences e.g 'BA'.

Each sequence is made up of 2 letters encoded as one-hot vectors. For example, the sequence 'BA' is `[[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]`.

(The sequences are longer in my original code but I want to keep my question simple)

I'm reasonably new to machine learning, I've done some stuff before but only with flat inputs. I'm struggling to understand how I can pass a multi-dimensional input into my network. Do I need to flatten it somehow?

**I've created a minimally reproducible example here -** https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhg3huw6bh7dfjd/Example.py?dl=0, `Sequences` only contains 3 examples of training data to keep it simple. I just need help working out how to pass 3d inputs into my model.

In the code I've provided, the entire dataset is just the following:

```
Sequences = [  [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]   ,  [[0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]  ,   [[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]  ]
```

It is a binary classifier, Targets for these sequences are:

```
Targets = [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

If you run the code I've provided you should get this error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 2, 2, 4]
```

If someone could help figure out how to correctly pass the sequences into my network that would be great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is the culprit. LSTM expects 3 dimensional input. In your case you are trying to pass a 4 dimensional input (remember that Keras add an additional batch dimension to the input shape). So, getting rid of the first `2` will solve your issue.

```
model.add(LSTM(128,
                   input_shape=(2, 2, 4), return_sequences=True))
```

Simply change this to,

```
model.add(LSTM(128,
                   input_shape=(2, 4), return_sequences=True))
```